# Azure Pipeline Trigger still referencing main after changing default to master

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Encountering an issue with azure pipelines:

```
Unable to resolve the reference 'refs/heads/main' to a specific version. Verify the reference exists in the source repository.
```

[Error List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsbdZ.png)
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbpNt.png)
Recently we have changed the default branch from main to master. The repo doesn't even have a main branch. The pipeline also doesn't trigger main.

The pipeline:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
- pipeline: uipipeline
  source: somesourceA
  trigger:
    branches:
      include:
        - develop
- pipeline: backendpipeline
  source: somesourceB
  trigger:
    branches:
      include:
        - master
```

Branches in repo:

[image: Branch List]

Things tried:

Checked YAML trigger settings. Its set to "master"

Comment: How do you run the Pipeline? Can you share a screenshot of the error in the running interface? And if possible can you share more yaml code sample with us? The current pipeline resources do not contain repo-related information.

Comment: gets triggered automatically when any commits are made to sourceA and sourceB . I'm afraid I can't share Yaml code. But I can share the errors.

Comment: You can share the error page screenshot. And then you check if you have defined any repo resources in the YAML. Feel free to share the result.

Comment: Updated the question with error screenshots

Comment: One more question, when you edit this pipeline, can you see the yaml pipeline details in master branch?

Comment: Yes. When I edit, I can see the pipeline in master branch. There are no other branches in this repo. But it still referencing main for some reason

Comment: Can you try to manually run the pipeline for one time, then you can check if the automatic trigger can work after manually trigger?

Comment: You can use try to use the rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1 to check the  defaultBranch of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Check your branch settings here:

1. Triggers:

[image]

2. Get Sources:

[image]

Comment: checked that. It is set to master already.